# PowerPoint 2010 add-in export to image issue

Tags: c#, export, add-in, powerpoint, office-interop

I am currently finalizing some work on a PowerPoint add-in that is to support both 2007 and 2010. The simple requirement is to export all PowerPoint slides to images and then wrap them in a proprietary format.

Everything is working wonderful overall except that I have noticed one issue when exporting from PowerPoint 2010. I am getting a small transparent border on the right (4px) and bottom (3px). I am not 100% sure if the image is offset or just skewed, but I am guessing it is actually offset (-4px,-3px).

I have searched the internet for a resolution but have not found much of anything in regards to my issue.

My question is: Has anyone here witnessed this issue themselves? If so were you able to resolve it?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue through the following steps:

1. Detecting the version of PowerPoint.
2. If 2010 then I export 4 pixels wider and 3 pixels taller (1028 x 771).
3. Crop the resulting image file to the desired 1024 x 768.

I don't know if there is a more elegant manner to resolve this, but this has done the trick for me.

Comment: I think the problem may've been fixed in the recently released SP1 for Office 2010.  Which is useful to know but won't bump your existing fix.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What resolution are you exporting at?
IIRC, you sometimes get this when you export images right at the max PPT permits, 3072 pixels.  If you're exporting anywhere near that, try reducing the output resolution to, say, 3000 pix.

Comment: OK, scratch the "too many pixels" theory. 
Are there full-frame images on the slides prior to export?  Images with embedded ICC profiles can produce borders at right and bottom when they're inserted. IOW, is it possible that it's the content of the slides that's causing the problem prior to the export?  Seems unlikely but thought I'd at least ask.

Comment: Currently I am just testing with a default template included with PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint sizes are not in standard (screen) pixels.  For example, if you want to save an image with a width and height of 300x300 pixels (respectively), then you must provide a width and height of 300/1.333333, where 1.33333 is an irrational, repeating number.  For this reason, sizes can be inappropriately rounded.   You should set your width/height as a float, providing as many decimal places as is necessary to achieve the desired result.  Do not use an integer.  Then let PowerPoint work out the difference.  This should get you to the proper dimensions on export.